# No route matches [GET]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add 'add to cart' method for my items.

items_controller:

```
def to_cart
  @item = Item.friendly.find(params[:id]) 
  @item.add_to_cart
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

routes:

```
resources :items do
  put :to_cart, on: :member
end
```

model:

```
def add_to_cart
  current_user.cart.items << self
  current_user.cart.save
end
```

show:

```
<%= @item.name  %>
<%= link_to 'add to cart', to_cart_item_path(@item) %>
```

I got RoutingError: `No route matches [GET] "/items/first/to_cart"`
'first' because of friendly id. 
What I did wrong?

Comment: Can you add your routes.rb?  You will need to add 'member: :to_cart' on the resources :items line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `method: :put` in your link by default it's `GET` and rails is trying to find the route with `GET` method

```
<%= link_to 'add to cart', to_cart_item_path(@item), method: :put %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Links on the web only send GET requests.

To send a `POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE` request you need to use a form.

```
<%= form_for to_cart_item_path(@item), method: :put do |f| %>
  <% f.submit 'Add to cart' %>
<% end %>
```

Rails provides a shortcut for this `button_to( 'add to cart', to_cart_item_path(@item) )`.

The Rails UJS driver (unobtrusive javascript driver) also provides a method that creates a form in the client when the link element has the `data-method` attribute:

```
<%= link_to 'add to cart', to_cart_item_path(@item), method: :put %>
```

Comment: However if your method is restful or uses the HTTP verb semantics properly is very debatable. PUT requests alter or replace an existing resource. What you are doing is adding a resource to the cart. Not changing an item. This may seem trivial but is a pretty important design decision.