# Match multiple paths to single controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

In my app, coins may or may not belong to networks. Hence I have the following in my `routes.rb`:

```
resources :coins

resources :networks do
    resources :coins
end
```

You can follow `coins` via coins#follow and unfollow them via coins#unfollow

This is working just fine for coins which belong to networks via:

```
match 'networks/:network_id/coins/:id/follow', to: 'coins#follow', via: 'get', :as => :follow_coin

match 'networks/:network_id/coins/:id/unfollow', to: 'coins#unfollow', via: 'get', :as => :unfollow_coin
```

I'd like to do this as well:

```
match 'coins/:id/follow', to: 'coins#follow', via: 'get', :as => :follow_coin

match '/coins/:id/unfollow', to: 'coins#unfollow', via: 'get', :as => :unfollow_coin
```

But I am getting this error when visiting `coins/coinname`, for example:

```
Invalid route name, already in use: 'follow_coin' You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming.
```

I am unclear on what the proper solution is. I'd like to map both `networks/:network_id/coins/:id/follow` and `coins/:id/follow` to the `coins#follow` action, which is already prepared to handle coins that belong to networks and coins that don't.

I suspect that even with:

```
match 'networks/:network_id/coins/:id/follow', to: 'coins#follow', via: 'get', :as => :follow_coin
```

I could be doing this better with `networks` resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what seaify said (great advice!), you could just do:

```
resource :coins do
  member do
    put :follow
    put :unfollow
  end
end
```

Then, when you want to use the `network_id`, do something like (assuming you have a `@coin` variable defined):

```
follow_coin_path(network_id: network_id)
```

Which will give you something like:

```
/coins/2/follow?network_id=1
```

And your params will be something like:

```
{..., id: 2, network_id: 1, ...}
```

Since it sounds like you already have the logic to determine whether the `network_id` parameter is present.

If you're trying to use `coinname` as the identifying variable (instead of `id`), then do something like:

```
resources :coins, param: :coinname do 
  member do 
    put :follow
    put :unfollow
  end
end
```

When you do `rake routes`, you should see something like:

```
   follow_coin PUT    /coins/:coinname/follow(.:format)        coins#follow
 unfollow_coin PUT    /coins/:coinname/unfollow(.:format)      coins#unfollow
         coins GET    /coins(.:format)                         coins#index
               POST   /coins(.:format)                         coins#create
      new_coin GET    /coins/new(.:format)                     coins#new
     edit_coin GET    /coins/:coinname/edit(.:format)          coins#edit
          coin GET    /coins/:coinname(.:format)               coins#show
               PATCH  /coins/:coinname(.:format)               coins#update
               PUT    /coins/:coinname(.:format)               coins#update
               DELETE /coins/:coinname(.:format)               coins#destroy
```

And your params will contain something like:

```
{..., coinname: 'bitcoin', ...}
```

Also, when you're using `link_to`, remember to do:

```
link_to("Follow #{@coin.name}", follow_coin_path(@coin), method: :put)
```

If you don't use `method: :put`, then `link_to` generates a `get`. And you'll end up with the `No route matches [GET] "/coins/coinname/follow"` error.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the right track. I have done as you said but when I do follow_coin path without a network id (for coins that don't belong to a network) I get this routing error: `No route matches [GET] "/coins/coinname/follow"`

Comment: I'm not sure where `coinname` is coming from. Have you tried `follow_coin_path(@coin)` (assuming you have `@coin` defined)?

Comment: "coinname" is just the variable. `coins#show` would actually be something like `coins/bitcoin`. when I insert `<%= link_to("Follow #{@coin.name}", follow_coin_path(@coin) %> it links to `coins/bitcoin/follow` and I get the routing error above

Comment: Thanks for the edit @jvillian but I am still getting `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/coins/bitcoin/follow")` even with 
`resources :coins do
    member do
      put :follow
      put :unfollow
    end
  end`

Comment: Yep I just found the same answer via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640825/no-route-matches-get. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

It's ok to set same `controller#action` for different url.

But they should have different `route helper`, so in rails view or controller, we can generate corresponding url for them.

Change code to this

```
match 'networks/:network_id/coins/:id/follow', to: 'coins#follow', via: 'get', :as => :network_follow_coin
match 'coins/:id/follow', to: 'coins#follow', via: 'get', :as => :follow_coin
```

So when use `network_follow_coin(network_id, coin_id)`, it generate url `/networks/1/coins/2/follow`.

When use `follow_coin_path(coin_id)`, it generate url `/coins/2/follow`.

As to simplify code, you should use `resource` for better wrap and understand, reduce the use of `match`(actually i think never). Change to this way

```
resource :networks do
   resource :coins do
     member do
       put :follow
       put :unfollow
     end
   end
end
```

And another thing is that if you change something in your database, you shouldn't set `http method` as `get`. If it's `get` method, it suppose to just fetch data, no modify. It's also dangerous, because some spiders keep visit every link in your websites, it might activate some bad things.